# iOS Metal: How to Capture GPU Frame properly?

Tags: ios, xcode, profiling, metal, compute-shader

I'm trying to profile Metal kernels by capturing GPU frame. In an application with Metal runloop I'd click on the "camera button" in the Debug area, however I only dispatch the kernels exactly once per application lifetime, thus I cannot click the "camera button" (it stays grayed out).

Because of this, I've tried to solve this problem by setting a breakpoint with action "Capture GPU Frame" before the first call of `mQueue.insertDebugCaptureBoundary()` (see the code below).

What I expect to happen is something like [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Art/xcode_gpu_overview_program_2x.png) – i.e. an overview of execution duration of each kernel function with denoted percentages of time spent on executing individual lines of kernel functions.

What actually happens is: I get the described expected profiling overview very rarely. Most of the time (about 95% of time) I don't get such an profiling overview, but instead one of the following happens after I build and run the app:

- No "Debugging GPU Frame" window gets displayed – only the Status bar of XCode changes to "Capturing GPU Frame" with active spinner; illustration [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kACAk.png).
- The "Debugging GPU Frame" window gets displayed, however there're NO encoded commands showed, hence no execution times are shown and no GPU objects browser is present (by objects I mean MTLBuffers and MTLTextures); illustration [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4YjG.png).
- A titleless XCode window pops out saying "timed out (5)" and nothing else happens; illustration [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6opD.png).

The code below shows a simplified example of my problem (in case you are wondering; no, I don't have the computation logic in a ViewController - the code below is just a toy example ;)).

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {  
  // initialize Metal, create buffers, etc.  

  override func viewDidLoad() {  
    tick() // called exactly once – how to profile the the kernels?  
  }  

  func tick() {  
      // On this (empty) line, there's set a breakpoint with the action "Capture GPU Frame"  
      mQueue.insertDebugCaptureBoundary() // start frame capture here  
      let cmdBuff = mQueue.commandBuffer()  
      let compEnc = cmdBuff.computeCommandEncoder()  

      // ------- Dispatch several kernels -------  
      compEnc.setComputePipelineState(foo)  
      compEnc.setBuffer(..., offset: 0, atIndex: 0)  
      compEnc.setBuffer(..., offset: 0, atIndex: 1)  
      // ...  
      compEnc.dispatchThreadgroups(..., ...)  


      compEnc.setComputePipelineState(bar)  
      compEnc.setBuffer(..., offset: 0, atIndex: 0)  
      compEnc.setBuffer(..., offset: 0, atIndex: 1)  
      // ...  
      compEnc.dispatchThreadgroups(..., ...)  
      // ------- /Dispatch several kernels -------  

      compEnc.endEncoding()  
      cmdBuff.commit()  
      cmdBuff.waitUntilCompleted()  

      mQueue.insertDebugCaptureBoundary() // end the frame capture here  
  }  

}
```

Comment: Which version(s) of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @warrenm Xcode 7.3 (7D175). The testing device is iPhone 6S running iOS 9.3.5 (13G36).

Comment: It might not make a difference, but have you tried with Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1012) or Xcode 8 beta 6 (8S201h)?

Comment: @warrenm thanks for the tip. Not yet – right now I'm downloading the Xcode 8. I'll let you know if the new Xcode helped to resolve the issue.

Comment: @warrenm I've just installed Xcode 7.3.1 and tested the profiler, but the bug still persists. On the other hand, given that Xcode profiles the kernels as expected only randomly, it seems to me that the problem could involve timing at which the frame is captured (just a thought)... I have 3 questions, if you don't mind: 1) Do I call `insertDebugCaptureBoundary()` at the right places? 2) Is the breakpoint with "Capture GPU Frame" action the right way how to programmatically capture a frame? 3) and if so, then where should be the breakpoint placed?

Comment: I have met the same problem. Did you find any solution? thanks.

Comment: @RobertWang Unfortunately I have not resolved the problem. To be able to profile the compute pipeline, I ended up using *both* compute and render pipelines. So I'm rendering 60 FPS and per each frame I first compute data via the compute pipeline and then feed the data into the render pipeline. When using the render pipeline, the Capture Boundary is inserted internaly, so there's no need to do it manually. If you don't want to use the render pipeline, **I'd suggest trying to run the compute pipeline in a loop** (2-5 loops). For example in the above code: `tick();tick();tick();`. (Not tested.)

Comment: @sarasvati Thanks for the comments. I feel that this might be a bug for compute only pipeline. I used a loop to control the compute pipeline after I posted the question. The capture can be triggered, but there is no profiled data or results showing. So, there is really no useful information from this profiler.

Comment: @RobertWang Well, after 1 year I finally figured it out :) – see my answer. I think you definitely know about this, but I just wanted to remind you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS 11 we can use the [`MTLCaptureManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/tools_profiling_and_debugging/metal_gpu_capture) to reliably capture even one invocation of a compute kernel.

When you run the example below, it starts capturing. You can stop the capture either via the Xcode's "GPU Capture button" (see the image) or programmatically via `MTLCaptureManager`'s [`stopCapture()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcapturemanager/2869736-stopcapture) method.

[image: GPU Capture button]

```
// 1. First create the Metal device and command queue
let dev   = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
let queue = dev.makeCommandQueue()!

// 2. Access the shared MTLCaptureManager and start capturing
let capManager = MTLCaptureManager.shared()
capManager.startCapture(commandQueue: queue)

// 3. Encode commands into the queue
let cmdbuff = queue.makeCommandBuffer()!
let enc     = cmdbuff.makeComputeCommandEncoder()!

// encode your kernel

enc.endEncoding()
cmdbuff.commit()
```